# Good way to start up vagrant configuration as single-click app?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vagrant, virtualbox

I use vagrant to configure different VirtualBoxes under Linux.

My goal is that any colleague of mine would just have to visit a intranet-site and choose the VirtualBox that he wants to have on his/her machine.
After selecting one or multiple boxes he or she might just click onto "proceed with installation" so that the respective vagrant directory/ies with its Vagrantfile(s) is/are checked out and execution with vagrant up is triggered.

So I want to abstract as much as possible from the console and make it look state of the art / fancy.

What technologies should I use?

I thought of vue.js together with node.js?
Would that be a viable approach to get to my goal?

Comment: To make it more clear:

The aspect which is not so clear to me is how to execute a shell script from within the browser. I think this would be blocked for security reasons. Wouldn't it? Is there a way to ask the user for permission?

Comment: you can look at project like https://puphpet.com or http://rove.io (not really maintained anymore, but gives you an idea) I believe there's one site which provide ansible provisioning script but I cannot retrieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can abstract the Vagrantfile generation in a lot of ways (including [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082166/good-way-to-start-up-vagrant-configuration-as-single-click-app#comment79142835_46082166) but dealing with vagrant actions will be way harder.

Right now vagrant doesn't provide other interfaces to its API than using the cli, or creating a plugin. Calling cli command in a web app is feasible but bad idea IMO.

So only course of action left is creating a vagrant plugin that serve and demonize vagrant through a REST API(for example with sinatra at its core) and then create a simple external client service(with react for example). 
If you directly expose the ui through the plugin it will create a too strong coupling IMO.